# Loading and reading .dta file in Python

Tags: python, dta

I tried loading a large .dta file into Python (I used JupyterLab and Google Colab) with the following code:

```
"data = pd.read_stata('qog_std_ts_jan21.dta')"
```

OR

```
data = pd.read_stata('filename.dta', chunksize=100000)
```

and I get the following error:

"unpack requires a buffer of 1 bytes". What does this mean and how can I solve the issue?

Also, after uploading the .dta file into JupyterLab, when I try to click on it, it keeps on showing the following error: "Invalid response: 503 Service Unavailable". I didn't try to visualize the data directly in Google Colab because I do not know how to do it.